# Linear program with bounds on the optimization variable

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to maximize the following function

$$f(x)=-x$$

subject to $0 \leq x < c$, where $c > 0$ is a constant.

If I write out the Lagrangian and take the first-order condition, I get a $\lambda = -1$, but this violates the non-negativity of $\lambda \ge 0$ and complementary slackness $\lambda(c-x)=0$. Does this imply the constraint is slack/nonbinding ?

Lastly had the constraint looked like $x > c$, then $\lambda =1$ would have been the case.

But the constraint cannot bind because of strict inequality! Which implies $\lambda = 0$ must be true. Which is a contradiction.

The solution is obvious, I am simply wondering why common optimization techniques are not working with these two constraints for a linear objective function with a boundary solution.

Comment: how did you get $\lambda=-1$, should not it be $\lambda\ge -1$, because it is an inequality constrained optimization problem?

Comment: Lagrangian techniques do not always work if the gradients of the goal and constraint functions are linearly dependent, as is the case here. In technical lingo, the constraint qualification is violated.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce the non-negativity constraint, let $x =: t^2$. To enforce the *strict* inequality constraint $x \leq c$, introduce a **slack** variable $s$ such that $t^2 + s^2 = c$. We then have the following [QCQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & -t^2\\ \text{subject to} & t^2 + s^2 = c\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t^2\\ \text{subject to} & t^2 + s^2 = c\end{array}}$$

Define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal L (t, s, \lambda) := t^2 + \lambda (t^2 + s^2 - c)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish,

$$\begin{array}{rl} (1 + \lambda) t &= 0\\ \lambda s &= 0 \\ t^2 + s^2 &= c\end{array}$$

which produces two solutions

- $\color{blue}{(t, s, \lambda) = (0, \pm \sqrt c, 0)}$, which corresponds to $\color{blue}{x = 0}$, where the **minimum** is attained.
- $\color{blue}{(t, s, \lambda) = (\pm \sqrt c, 0,-1)}$, which corresponds to $\color{blue}{x = c}$, where the **maximum** is attained.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following linear program (LP) in $x \in \mathbb R$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & -x\\ \text{subject to} & 0 \leq x \leq c\end{array}$$

where $c > 0$. Rewriting the LP above in minimization form,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & 0 \leq x \leq c\end{array}$$

Introducing a (nonnegative) **slack** variable $s \in \mathbb R$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & x + s = c\\ & x, s \geq 0\end{array}$$

Let $\color{blue}{x_1 := \frac{x}{c}}$ and $\color{blue}{x_2 := \frac{s}{c}}$. Hence, we have the following LP

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & c x_1\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + x_2 = 1\\ & x_1, x_2 \geq 0\end{array}$$

whose feasible region is the $1$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), i.e., the line segment whose endpoints are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Since $c > 0$, the minimum is attained at $(x_1, x_2) = (0,1)$, which corresponds to $\color{blue}{x = 0}$ and $\color{blue}{s = c}$.